# Inserir uma mensagem de sucesso após o location.reload()

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, javascript-eventos

Gostaria de adicionar uma mensagem de editado com sucesso via JS após recarregar a página.
A mensagem é exibida antes de recarregar a página e não antes.

Segue meu código:

Chamada AJAX:

```
var resposta = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        id: idProjeto,
                        nome: nomeProjeto,
                        resumo: resumoProjeto,
                        dataInicio: dataInicioProjeto,
                        dataFim: dataFimProjeto
                    }
                ),
            error: onErroSalvandoProjeto.bind(this),
            success: onProjetoSalvo.bind(this)
        });
```

Estas são minhas funções:

```
function onProjetoSalvo(){
  
    location.reload();
    insertPrimaryAlert();
}

    function insertPrimaryAlert(){
        var alertPrimary = '<div class="alert alert-info"> Projeto editado com sucesso! </div>';
        document.getElementById('alertas').innerHTML = alertPrimary;
    }
```

Comment: Entendi, eu sou novo aqui no Stack, ainda estou me encontrando. Vou tirar o resolvido e a resposta já aceitei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso a página precisa armazenar um estado se o projeto foi salvo com sucesso, infelizmente ao recarregar a página você limpa todos os dados da sua aplicação. O que você pode fazer é salvar se a requisição foi efetuada com sucesso no [armazenamento do navegador](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), e, ao recarregar, verificar se o valor armazenado está como `true`.

```js
/**
 * Salva os dados para o armazenamento local
 * do navegador
 */
function saveSuccessfullRequestToLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem("_success", true);
}

/**
 * Apaga os dados salvos no armazenamento local
 * do navegador
 */
function clearSuccessfullRequest() {
  localStorage.removeItem("_sucessfull");
}

/**
 * Confere se a requisição foi feita com sucesso
 * insere o alerta e limpa os dados do armazenamento
 * local
 */
function checkSuccessfullRequest() {
  const successfullRequest = localStorage.getItem("_success");

  if (successfullRequest) {
    insertPrimaryAlert();
    clearSuccessfullRequest();
  }
}
```

Comment: Não sei nem como agradecer, perdi um dia de trabalho por causa disso e você me ajudou rapidão... Thank's mano, muito sucesso a você :)